# How to integrate sonar-scan in ballerina based applications?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, ballerina

I am using many repositories and in case of npm modules i can integrate sonar easily,however I also want to scan with sonar in my ballerina based modules.How do I set up the work flow?

I tried searching for it and could not find any.

Comment: As Ballerina-lang is relatively new, I don't think sonarqube support scanning Ballerina projects.